# Attach helpers to Jade when running client side (in browser)

Tags: node.js, express, pug, helper, i18next

I have made a single page app powered by node js (Express) with a mongo db. I have used jade for templating and have some templates rendered in the browser. The templates render fine except I am unable to workout how to add helpers. In particular i18next.

I have set up a route to template/get/ which  looks like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var jade = require('jade');


exports.get = function(req, res){

  fs.readFile('views/partials/listing_snippet.jade', {encoding: 'utf-8'}, function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data);
    t = jade.compile(data, {client: true, compileDebug: false});
    res.send('var template = {listing_snippet: ' + t.toString() + '}');
  });
}
```

I then include this and jades 'runtime.js' as scripts at the top of my page. The template renders fine by calling `template.listing_snippet({locals: foo});`

but I can not get i18next's helpers to work. I assume I need to attach the helper somehow... but the documentation is a little thin in that area.